# Uploading SQL file to GitHub repository

Tags: sql, github

I downloaded an SQL file from my Amazon web server, and intend to push it to the GitHub repository for my project. What is all the information in that file I should delete before making the push? (Bear in mind that it's a public repository.)

In the file, there are two things that I am worrying about: the host, and the login name, via the definer, which is of the form specified in the comments. (It won't render right here.)

Am I right to worry about either of them? If so, how to resolve these security problems?

Comment: treat it like anything else, what's in the file that shouldn't be publicly known? only you know

Comment: In the file, there are two things that I am worrying about: the host, and the login name, via the definer, which is of the form `\`loginName\`@\`%\``

Answer (score 2):

Seeing you asking this type of question I would answer: login names and password. If you are pushing it to public repository there is nothing you can do about the queries anyway.